# How to create generic id type properties?

Tags: ios4

I'm new to iOS and Objective-C and trying to create a class that has a generic property.

`@interface HeaderInfo : NSObject {
        NSString *label;
        id value;
    }`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id value;
- (HeaderInfo *)initWithLabel:(NSString *)lbl value:(id)val;

@end
```

Then I'm trying to add this class to an array:

`[generalSection.items addObject:[[HeaderInfo alloc] initWithLabel:@"Tacho seal security" value:@"Some String Value"]];`

[generalSection.items addObject:[[HeaderInfo alloc] initWithLabel:@"Tacho seal security" value:YES]];

but compiler doesn't like the 2nd addition and says:

`Warning: passing argument 2 of 'initWithLabel:value:' makes pointer from integer without a cast`

What I'm doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

And also how can check the value later on whether it's a BOOL or NSString?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BOOL` type is not a object, so you can't pass it as id (a generic object).

You should pass an `NSNumber`. An NSNumber is an object that encapsulate numbers when you want to pass a number as an object.

You can create a `NSNumber` like this : `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];`

You can retrieve the value with `[value boolValue];`

If you want to check the type of object you're having at runtime you can to it like that :

```
if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
   //It's a number
}
else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   //It's a string
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the way to go. The `NSNumber` class is a wrapper for the primitive data types.